# Why did mutation happen while filtering array of simple objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

By simple I mean that objects inside the array contains only primitives. According to spec:

> ... filter calls callbackfn once for each element in the array, in ascending order, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callbackfn returns true. ...

So why in this example I get basically the link to the initial array and not the new one???

```
console.clear();

const array = [
  {id: 1, parent: 0},
  {id: 2, parent: 1},
  {id: 3, parent: 1},
  {id: 4, parent: 1}
];

const newArray = array.filter(el => el.id === 2 && {...el});
const newArray2 = array.map(el => ({...el}));
newArray[0].children = 3; // mutation of initial array
const newEl = {...array[2]};

console.log('Array: ', array);
console.log('newArray2: ', newArray2);
console.log('array[1] === newArray[0]: ', array[1] === newArray[0]); // WTF???
console.log('array[1] === newArray2[1]: ', array[1] === newArray2[1]);
console.log('newEl === array[2]: ', newEl === array[2]);
```

https://codepen.io/fanich37/pen/NEEqNp

Comment: In `newArray[0].children = 3;` you are mutating an _object_ that is _in_ both the new array and the original one. It seems you're not using `filter` correctly. The `{...el}` in your filter line doesn't do anything here. All you need to do to observe that `array` and `newArray` are separate arrays is to observe the value of `array === newArray` (it's false).

Comment: Yes, `filter` is not for deep copying objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Array.filter** does not return the `object`, it simply returns `true` and `false`. When it returns `true`, the value of the original array is pushed to the new array. As `objects` are **passed by reference**, they continue to share the reference even though they are being referred in 2 arrays.

Hence, you need to change the logic here to make sure the references have been changed i.e. you add an object pointing to some different reference.

You can use `Array.map` like following

```js
const array = [{id: 1, parent: 0},{id: 2, parent: 1},{id: 3, parent: 1},{id: 4, parent: 1}];

const newArray = array.filter(el => el.id === 2).map(el => ({...el}));
console.log('array[1] === newArray[0]: ', array[1] === newArray[0]);
```

OR you can use `Array.reduce` like following

```js
const array = [{id: 1, parent: 0},{id: 2, parent: 1},{id: 3, parent: 1},{id: 4, parent: 1}];

const newArray = array.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(c.id===2) a.push({...c});
  return a;
}, []);
console.log('array[1] === newArray[0]: ', array[1] === newArray[0]);
```

Comment: @AndreyAlexandrov - Glad to help you :)